# PHP mail não envia o e-mail

Tags: php

Venho encontrando um problema em fazer um formulario de contato, pois não estou obtendo sucesso e não sei o motivo de não funcionar.

Segue código aplicado:

**HTML**

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="POST" action="contact_me.php" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SEU NOME*" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Seu nome faltou.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="SEU E-MAIL*" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, adicione um email.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="SEU TELEFONE*" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, adicione um telefone.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="SUA MENSAGEM*" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, adicione uma mensagem."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl anime">ENVIAR MENSAGEM</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

if (!$_POST['submit'])
{
    $quebra_linha = "\n"; 
    $emailsender = "email@dominio.com"; 
    $nomeremetente = $_REQUEST['name']; 
    $emaildestinatario = "email@dominio.com"; 
    $assunto = "[CONTATO] SITE RESPONSAVEL"; 
    $mensagem = $_REQUEST['message']; 
    $email = $_REQUEST['email']; 
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];

    $mensagemHTML = ' Olá, 
    tenho uma nova mensagem para você diretamente do site!

    Nome: '.$nomeremetente.' Assunto: '.$empresa.' E-mail: '.$email.' Telefone: '.$phone.' Mensagem: '.$mensagem.'';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$quebra_linha; 
    $headers = "From: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha; 
    $headers = "Reply-To: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;

    if (mail($emaildestinatario, $assunto, $mensagemHTML, $headers, "-r". $emailsender)) {
        echo ""; 
        echo ""; 
    } else { 
        echo ""; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Aparentemente o `action=""` não esta redirecionando quando aperto no botão `submit`. Tentei com o PHPMailer também, porém encontro o mesmo problema.
O index foi salvo como index.php e ja tentei utilizar o `PHP_SELF`, porém não obtive muito sucesso também.

Comment: Qual erro apresenta? Ou não está passando valores?

Comment: **Dica**: No PHP existe uma constante chamada [`PHP_EOL`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.constants.php) que pode ser utilizada para quebra de linhas.

Comment: Não é apresentado nenhum erro pois ele não redireciona para action;

Comment: Considerando a existência dos atributos `data-validation-required-message` você deve estar utilizando alguma biblioteca JS para validação do formulário. Se sim, qual é? Geralmente essas bibliotecas atuando no evento `submit` do formulário e, se de alguma forma estiver retornando `false`, a requisição é cancelada.

Comment: `!$_POST['submit']`? Não seria `if($_POST['submit'])` ou `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`? Veja no F12 do navegador qual é a resposta e se está enviado a requisição como deseja, assim poderá isolar o problema, se é no cliente ou no servidor.

Comment: Da um `name` para o `submit`, e coloca no `if(isset($_POST['nomedosubmit'])){echo "Passou";}`

Comment: Se não muda o final da url do navegador para contact_me.php, então existe javascript brecando a submissão do formulário como relatado pelo @AndersonCarlosWoss, se muda a url, então basta seguir os comentários do Inkeliz, Max Rogério e respostas enviadas.

Answer (score 5):

Não existe nenhum input com nome submit em seu HTML. Logo, o if nunca será executado.
Aliás, nenhum de seus inputs tem o atributo "name". A captura de um campo envia via post é feita através do name deste campo. Exemplo

```
<form method="post>
   <input type="text" name="nome_do_campo"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

O PHP iria pegar o campo acima desta forma:

```
<?php
$campo = $_POST['nome_do_campo'];
?>

<?php
//Se quisermos executar o código só se o POST tiver sido feito:
if(isset($_POST['nome_do_campo']))
{
   $campo = $_POST['nome_do_campo'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Tem um <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl anime">ENVIAR MENSAGEM</button> no form dele. Funciona do mesmo jeito que o input.

Comment: Se o form dele não tiver sendo barrado por javascript, então o problema é aquele if do começo que supõe que existe uma variável $_POST['submit'] e pega o valor contrário , quando o correto seria por um name="submit" no botão do form html e checar se ela existe usando if(isset($_POST['submit'])) no script php.

Answer (score 0):

RESUMO DA ÓPERA:

> No PHP tire o sinal de negação (ponto de exclamação) antes do $_POST.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ .....
```

Modificações no Código HTML:

> Dar name para todos os inputs para que o PHP possa obter os dados do formulário HTML

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="POST" action="contact_me.php" novalidate>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SEU NOME*" name="name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Seu nome faltou.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="SEU E-MAIL*" name="email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, adicione um email.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="SEU TELEFONE*" name="phone" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, adicione um telefone.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="SUA MENSAGEM*" name="message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, adicione uma mensagem."></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div id="success"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="vete" class="btn btn-xl anime">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Esse name="submit" que você pôs que fez a diferença. Mas devia ter posto a checagem com `if( isset($_POST['submit']) )` . Se tiver usando button com type="submit" ou input type="submit" dá no mesmo. Você respondeu a pergunta corretamente mas escorregou nesse detalhe. Achei injusto você ter recebido dois negativos na sua resposta pois você identificou o problema corretamente. Dei um +1 pra diminuir a injustiça.

Comment: Valeu  Antonio Alexandre. O que acontece é que muitos votam negativo e acho que sequer fazem alguma experiencia ou postam algo pra ajudar. Eu simplesmente tive o trabalho de colocar online no meu servidor e testar todas as formas até que desse um resultado satisfatório. E acredite do jeito que postei com button não funfa nem a pau!!! Será que falta alguma biblioteca?

Comment: É bom saber que quem faz alguma página pra postar na internet tem que ter ciência que há uma infinidade de variações (navegadores, versões de navegadores, etcc) que podem definir se o treco funfa ou não. Não adiante por em pratica algo que só atente aos mais atualizados.